# Readmission count based on first admit date postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table "visits" with sample data:

> patient_id | date_admitted | date_discharged |
>
> 971        |2011-03-25  | 2011-03-25|
>
> 971        |2011-08-08  |2011-08-08 |
>
> 971        |2011-08-25  |2011-08-25 |
>
> 971        |2011-09-03  |2011-09-03 |
>
> 971        |2011-10-03  |2011-10-09 |

I am trying to get a count of readmissions for the patient based on two conditions

1) Within 0 through 30 days.

2) Within 31 through 90 days.

Desired result:

> patient_id | readmission_count_30| readmission_count_90|
>
> 971        | 2                   | 1 |

Readmission_count_30 : "2" because two admit dates present in the data beginning from admit date 2011-08-08 and ending within 2011-09-08

Readmission_count_90 : "1" because one admit date present in the data beginning from admit date 2011-08-08, and one admit date is present within the date ranges 2011-08-08 + interval '31 days' and 2011-08-08 + interval '90 days'

I have tried to get the readmission_count_30 but the logic is flawed.

```
    select admit.patient_id,count(*)
    from visits admit 
    left outer join (select r1.patient_id, r1.date_admitted, r1.date_discharged,
    r2.id as readmit_type 
    from visits r1) readmit 
    on admit.patient_id = readmit.patient_id and 
    admit.date_admitted < readmit.date_admitted and readmit.date_admitted between admit.date_admitted AND           
    admit.date_admitted + INTERVAL '30 days' 
    group by admit.patient_id
```

Comment: Please explain why do you want to count from admit date 2011-08-08 ? How do you know that the query must count from THIS particular date, not from other dates ?

Comment: @kordirko - I do not want a count from that particular admit date. I just gave it as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1092d/1)

```
select
    patient_id,
    count(
        date_admitted > '2011-08-08'
        and date_admitted <= '2011-08-08'::date + interval '30 days'
        or null
    ) as readmission_count_30,
    count(
        date_admitted > '2011-08-08'::date + interval '30 days'
        and date_admitted <= '2011-08-08'::date + interval '90 days'
        or null
    ) as readmission_count_90
from visits
group by patient_id
```

Generalized version

```
select
    patient_id,
    count(
        date_admitted > first_admitted
        and date_admitted <= first_admitted + interval '30 days'
        or null
    ) as readmission_count_30,
    count(
        date_admitted > first_admitted + interval '30 days'
        and date_admitted <= first_admitted + interval '90 days'
        or null
    ) as readmission_count_90
from
    visits
    inner join
    (
        select patient_id, min(date_admitted) as first_admitted
        from visits
        group by patient_id
    ) f using (patient_id)
group by patient_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Your answer worked for that particular data. When I tried to generalize the query by adding min(date_admitted) in the place of '2011-08-08', an error occurred saying aggregate function calls cannot be nested. Could you help me generalize it?

Comment: @user2212872 Updated but it shows zero for the supplied data as the first admission is `2011-03-25`

Comment: Ya. I understand. Do you suggest I try using cursors as I need to go row by row for each patient and compare previous date_admitted to the next date_admitted for each patient? Using min(date_admitted) is not giving me the expected result. Or is there any other way I can achieve it?

Comment: @user2212872 I don't understand your comment. My update answer does exactly what you asked for.